# Как отобразить изображения с разых папок в разных постах

Tags: django

Делаю слайдер изображений для разных постов. На всех постах разные картинки слайдера.

Ищю способ как добавлять к посту нужную папку для вывода всех изображений в слайдер.

Есть папки с картинками. Каждая папка относится к отдельному посту.
Задача выводить все содержимое папки (все картинки) относящееся к своему посту. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Media - папка

img_post1 - папка и картинками

img_post2 - папка и картинками

img_post3 - папка и картинками

```
class category(models.Model):
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('URL'))
        description = models.TextField(max_length=700, verbose_name=('Описание'), blank=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.slug
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})
        
    class post(models.Model):
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('URL'))
        description = models.TextField(max_length=700, verbose_name=('Описание'), blank=False)
    
        cat = models.ForeignKey('category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.slug
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_slug': self.slug})


 
        Views
     
    def ContentСategory(request, category_slug):
        category = get_list_or_404(post, slug=category_slug)
        category=category.objects.filter(slug=category_slug)
        return render(request, 'content/category.html',{'category':category})
    
    def ContentPost(request, post_slug):
        post = get_list_or_404(post, slug=post_slug)
        post=post.objects.filter(slug=post_slug)
        return render(request, 'content/post.html',{'post':post})
```